# Automatically generate getters and setters in Android Studio in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to find a way to generate getters and setters of some Kotlin  property automatically. In java there is no problem to do it.

I am working with data binding and I have many classes which looks like so:

```
class AnimalListItemPresenter(private var _animal: String) : BaseObservable() {
    var animal: String
        @Bindable get() = _animal
        set(value) {
            _animal = value
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.item)
        }

}
```

I know that it is not possible not possible to generate the logic in setter but can I at leat somehow generate the standard getter and setter?

Comment: use data class!

Comment: There is no "standard getter and setter" in Kotlin. Or, rather, they are built into the language. Your `get()` and `set()` are overriding the "standard getter and setter".

Comment: In Kotlin, fields are already translated into standard getters and setters. Why not just add your custom setter to the constructor field?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard getters and setters are built into Kotlin.

example:

```
class Customer {
  var id = "",
  var name = ""
}
```

and you can use it like:

```
fun copyCustomer(customer: Customer) : Customer {
    val result = Customer() 
    result.name = customer.name 
    .
    .
    return result
}
```

You can also override the default getter and setter in the manner you have done in the code snippet. Good Resource: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

If you want a quick way of generating boilerplate code in Android Studio -> Alt + Enter`on the property and you can`Add Getter`or`Add Setter` among different options

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
class BannerBean {
private var id: String? = null
private var image: String? = null
private var link: String? = null

fun getId(): String? {
    return id
}

fun setId(id: String?) {
    this.id = id
}

fun getImage(): String? {
    return image
}

fun setImage(image: String?) {
    this.image = image
}

fun getLink(): String? {
    return link
}

fun setLink(link: String?) {
    this.link = link
}
```

}